# Как сделать градиентную тень у текста?

Tags: html, css

В фигме есть такой текст:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В фигме это реализовано наложением друг на друга нескольких слоев текста. Можно ли это сделать на CSS?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать градиентную обводку у текста?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1492027/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d1%83-%d1%83-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0)

Answer (score 1):

Вот типа того, но не знаю как сделать градиент горизонтальный.

```css
p {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  text-shadow:3px 3px 10px red,-3px -3px 10px yellow;
}
```

```html
<p>25000 Dollars</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
body { background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #24293f, #293c5c); }

h1 {
  position: relative;
  font: 64px/1em 'Arial Black', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
h1::before {
  content: '25 000 RUB';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #f53d5c, #79a9ec);
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 5px transparent;
  text-stroke: 5px transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  filter: blur(2px);
}
```

```html
<h1>25 000 RUB</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример с svg: https://codepen.io/sethjenks/pen/KpNJZp

Хотя мне кажется твой пример слишком кастомный и его можно было вставить как картинку в вёрстку. Если нужно, чтоб можно было выделять, можно поверх картинки белый текст сделать, подогнав.

Моя идея: сделать 2 слоя с одинаковым текстом, используя абсолютное позиционирование. Верхний слою сделать color: #fff. А нижнему слою задать linear-gradient. Если делать такую штуку для каждой буквы, можно замарочиться и сделать красиво.
Вот я что-то пробовал, может наводки какие-то даст.

```css
.text {
  position: relative;
  font-family: sans-serif;
 
}

.text-down {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 72px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(-180deg, red, blue);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  top: 0;
}

.text-up {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.5px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 68px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
<span class="text-down">25 000 РУБ</span>
<span class="text-up">25 000 РУБ</span>
</div>
```

Интересный вопрос, не сталкивался с таким.