# Как сделать градиентную обводку у текста?

Tags: html, css

Есть такая картинка. Как у текста можно сделать такую градиентную обводку на CSS?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример

```css
body {
  background-color: #D9D9D9;
}

h1 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #f00 0%, #00f 60%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 4px transparent;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

h1::selection {
   color: #fff;
   background-color: #00f;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #000;
}
```

```html
<h1>Забери свой бонус</h1>
```

Comment: Попробуйте выделить одно слово (или букву) из предложения.

Comment: @ΝNL993 - текст выделяется + выделение можно изменить под свои нужды

Comment: А у меня вся обводка пропадает. [Вот пример](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtaIl.png).

Comment: @ΝNL993 - какое отношение имеет обводка к выделению текста?

Comment: Разве по вопросу у текста не должно быть обводки? Если я вдруг выделил текст значит обводка должна попасть?

Comment: @ΝNL993 проблема у вас. [У меня](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bokQ2.png) все нормально. Браузер:  Microsoft Edge 109.0.1518.70.

Comment: @ΝNL993 -  у текста обводка есть, по поводу ```::selection``` ничего не сказано

Comment: @eccs0103 Хм, странно, а у меня не работает. Браузер: Firefox 108.0.1.

Comment: @soledar10 а я и не про `::selection` говорю :р, у меня просто пропадает обводка при выделении текста. По моему будет правильным ответить что ваш ответ работает не корректно в моих условиях.

Comment: @ΝNL993 https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/::selection вроде для выделения текста

Comment: @ΝNL993 [в документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip) кроме `-webkit-background-clip: text;` стиль `background-clip: text;` добавлено. Думаю Firefox не поддерживает стиль с `-webkit`.

Comment: @soledar10 да, про выделение текста, но дело в том что обводка убирается с текста который даже НЕ выделен.

Comment: @eccs0103 попробовал добавить `background-clip: text;`, всё равно та же проблема. Да и к тому же обводка пропадает при выделении текста, если текст не выделять, то всё нормально.

Comment: @eccs0103 может написать о баге в bugzilla.mozilla.org?

Comment: @ΝNL993 интересно стало. Иду установить Mozilla, попробовать. :)

Comment: @ΝNL993 интересный такой браузер. Пропадает именно [с той строки который выделен](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlTn0.png).

Comment: @ΝNL993 да, оформите как баг. Тут нет никакой логики, просто криво написан.